# BibTeX bibliography doesn't display when compiling using AUCTeX

Tags: bibtex, auctex

I created a simple BibTeX file as well as a simple LaTeX file that references said BibTeX file. When I compile document in AUCTeX using `C-c` `C-a`, the bibliography section doesn't appear and the citations are broken: [according to the AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#One-Command-for-LaTeX_002c-helpers_002c-viewers_002c-and-printing) this command should run the LaTeX-BibTeX-LaTeX-LaTeX cycle. The file itself is fine as verified by running the same cycle manually.

```
%% Bibliography.bib
@book{WEN08,
    Author = {Jochen Wengenroth},
    Date-Added = {2017-05-08 08:16:51 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-05-08 08:19:24 +0000},
    Publisher = {de Gruyter},
    Title = {Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie},
    Year = {2008}}

%% MyDoc.tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{WEN08}. 

\bibliography{Bibliography}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting pdf file with a blank bibliography and a broken citation]

---

AUCTeX 11.90.0
Emacs 25.1.1
TeX Live 2016, v. 3.14159265
macOS Sierra, v. 10.12.4

Comment: I tried with repeated `C-c`: the first attempt has “Default LaTeX”, the subsequent ones have “Default View”. There's no offer about doing BibTeX, so `C-c C-a` doesn't do it either. So it seems a bug of AUC-TeX: it is supposed to do that, but it doesn't

Comment: @JosephWright: I tried running it from the command line and indeed the bibliography was generated. So if this is a problem with my AUCTeX installation, where can I ask for help? Not in this forum?

Comment: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2016-10/msg00026.html

Comment: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24771

Comment: @egreg: I don't think the bug report you linked to is applicable to the present situation, since it seems that in the bug report the problem was the existence of multiply defined labels, whereas in the present case there are no multiply defined labels.

Comment: Well, I believe the minimal example has some redundant bits, because yours exhibits the same issue without multiply defined labels.

Comment: Crosspost: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/32656/620

Comment: On that basis I'll close here (it is an Emacs issue and there is now a good question on the network about it)

Comment: Just a question for those who can reproduce the issue (not me): what does `C-h v` `LaTeX-bibliography-list` `RET` return in `MyDoc.tex` buffer?  The value of the variable should be `(("Bibliography"))`.